# Redirect to different URL in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7.5, asp.net-mvc-routing, redirect

How to pass value url value in RedirecttoAction with Controller and Action with parameters.
**Condition**
On Post of an action in `site1 (https://www.xyz.com)`, redirect to site2 `(https://www.abc.com/controller/action/parameter)` .
How can I pass the url with controller name and action in site1. 
I tried checking like this example

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Product",
    "Product/{productId}",
    new {controller="Product", action="Details"}
);
```

But how can I add the url `https://www.abc.com` ?
Any suggestions.

Comment: I think this would be better done as an IIS rewrite rule. There should be plenty of examples out there if you search for IIS rewrite rules.

Comment: cant you do a simple `return Redirect("http://www.abc.com/controller/action/parameter");`. You can pass Controller and action name in the Request Body of the post.